# cyclic quad, circle theorems, that came on my test

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry

I have a question from a geometry test.

AB is parallel to CD

[image: trapezoid inscribed in a circle]

I got Angle CBD = 180-x because angles on a straight line are equal.

Answer (score 2):

Since $ABCD$ is cyclic trapezoid it must be isosceles, so the $\angle CDB =x$.

Or 
$$ \angle CDB = 180-\angle DBA = \angle ACD$$

Comment: it can be a rectangle as well but it leads to the same result

Comment: Rip me. Well, so CDB = 180-x is right or not?

Comment: Not in general. Only if $x=90$.

Comment: How is ABCD isoceles?

Comment: You have full prove written.